# Latest Bootstrap 5.1 dropdown examples not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I can't get the latest bootstrap 5.1.x examples for dropdowns to work out of the box.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/dropdowns/

If I use the source code from the examples, the dropdowns would not show.

I compared the bootstrap classes, and apparently bootstrap's .dropdown-menu is different.

In my case, .dropdown-menu looks as follows:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

This seems fine, however, as it's in accordance with bootstrap's latest release, see class .dropdown-menu in their git repository https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/dist/css/bootstrap.css

However, in their official dropdown example, the mentioned class looks as follows:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 4rem auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
}
```

I can't believe that I should simply replace the official dropdown class. So any ideas how to use the examples properly? I can't find any further info on their webpage.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a fiddle with the dropdown: https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/je3t8yf7/2/ . What is different between in the code here and yours?

Comment: Your example is just a regular dropdown button?!  I refer to the 5.1.x dropdown samples as listed above (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/dropdowns/)

Comment: Please provide a working snippet in your question to demonstrate the problem. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Be aware that libraries often modify HTML on render to make components work and apply config options. You should not be copying rendered page code (which isn't really _source_ code). You should get your code from the actual source code or documentation.

Comment: @TeaCup My mistake, I misread. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Using just the Bootstrap CSS file will give a default dropdown. The example in your link is not the 'official' dropdown, it's a customised macos version, provided by the Bootstrap team themselves. And yes, it needs some custom CSS. The CSS you wrote was only partial and that is why it was not working.
The actual CSS you need to add is:

```
.dropdown-menu {  
    position: static;  
    display: block;  
    width: auto;  
    margin: 4rem auto; 
} 
.dropdown-menu-macos {  
    display: grid;  
    gap: .25rem;  
    padding: .5rem; 
    border-radius: .5rem; 
}
.dropdown-menu-macos .dropdown-item {  
    border-radius: .25rem; 
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/yvqjkxr0/2/)